# If someone has a video recorded for 1 minute and then deleted immediately on Android phone, can it be leaked to the internet?

Tags: privacy, mobile, android

I recorded 720p not good material for myself on my Android phone for 1 min or a little more. Then I delete it immediately. I didn't send the video over the internet, I just kept it on local memory and then I delete it.

Is it possible for a hacker to get the video from my phone and leak it to the internet to **** sites in this very small amount of time? I checked my cloud services like Google drive, Dropbox, etc. They did not upload anything.

Could hackers search for Android users among 1.5 billion users and choose randomly one and get his/her data like an attack on the mobile phone?

Comment: Your nudes are safe, don't worry.

Comment: How sophisticated is your adversary?

Answer (score 2):

Potentially, yes it is possible that any data on a connected device has been sent to a 3rd party. any device can be compromised to do things that its owner does not wish it to do (like send data or store deleted data).

Has it happened to you? I very much doubt it.

Comment: No ,the file deleted after one minture how it could be sent to 3rd party under these condition that I mention @Topher Brink

Comment: Easily. If you had malware already on your phone, if you had some sort of application that makes backups on a regular basis etc... But like Topher said, the chances are slim to none. Sure it ***could have*** happened, even under the conditions you described, but the chances are so ridiculously unlikely that you really shouldn't be concerned.

Comment: No it seems you didn't understand the question @TopherBrink

Comment: You say all users who have naked data there is a possiablity to be leaked to the internet

Comment: Anyone who has a connected device is susceptible to having their information compromised in some capacity. Full stop. The naked data is infinitely more interesting, mind you, but chances of this happening is a different question entirely. Unless you're Jennifer Lawrence, I doubt anyone cares about your video (no offense). You are one of many fish in a great big sea of nakedness.

Comment: yes, potentially any data that is collected can be done anything with. Systems get compromised when they interact with foreign data sources (by foreign i mean not originating from itself) this could be a usb device, internet connection, person, its own camera. Compromised machines do a upto 3 things, collect data, send data, compute things.  potentially your phone could have saved your video to another folder as well as the expected folder to be sent next time you have a net connection. but as i have said before, this is unlikely. dont become too paranoid, its bad for you, i know 1st hand :P

Answer (score 0):

Once the file is deleted, you are kind of safe. They could do data recovery and try to get the file (which is really hard, and is probably more torture than getting bad pictures leaked). You want to rewrite the drive w/ zeros and ones. You should be safe, it isn't very practical to send every single android users' (or whatever device you are using) videos to a single server, then write some kind of AI that searches for adult material. I highly doubt that would be very profitable or practical for any criminal to do. You are pretty safe, as long as no one knows.